# VBA Excel - Trying to match 2 excel files by comapring 6 columns

Tags: excel, file, vba, match

I have two excel files.  I am looping thru file 1 and trying to find the corresponding row in file 2 using 6 different columns.  I do not think VLOOKUP works for this multiple criteria.  I am at a loss as to how to do it.  To state the problem differently I am looping thru file 1.  Using the values in cols F,G,H,I,J,K  - I am trying to find the matching row in file 2  using cols K,AK,AF,E,N,G. When I find a match I move data from file 2 to the corresponding row in file 1. Any ideas?

Comment: Which data columns are you trying to transfer?

Comment: This would be a good use for SUMPRODUCT, you can get a good intro here: http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/11/10/excel-sumproduct-formula/

Answer (score 1):

The attached code will match the columns, you can update it to do the transfer

```
Sub MatchMultipleColumns()
Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Dim lLastRow As Long, lLoop As Long, rgFound As range, rgLastFound As range

Set wbk1 = Workbooks("file 1.xls")
Set wbk2 = Workbooks("file 2.xls")

Set sht1 = wbk1.Sheets(1)
Set sht2 = wbk2.Sheets(2)

lLastRow = sht1.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)

For lLoop = 1 To lLastRow
    Set rgLastFound = sht2.Cells(1, "K")

tryAgain:
    Set rgFound = sht2.Columns("K").Find(What:=sht1.Cells(lLoop, "F"), After:=rgLastFound, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If rgFound Is Nothing Then GoTo nxtRow

    If sht2.Cells(rgFound.Row, "AK") = sht1.Cells(lLoop, "G") _
        And sht2.Cells(rgFound.Row, "AF") = sht1.Cells(lLoop, "H") _
        And sht2.Cells(rgFound.Row, "E") = sht1.Cells(lLoop, "I") _
        And sht2.Cells(rgFound.Row, "N") = sht1.Cells(lLoop, "J") _
        And sht2.Cells(rgFound.Row, "G") = sht1.Cells(lLoop, "K") Then

        'INSERT YOUR TRANSFER CODE HERE
        Debug.Print "Found match for row " & lLoop & " at row " & rgFound.Row
    Else
        set rgLastFound=rgFound
        GoTo tryAgain
    End If

nxtRow:
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you may want to use index and match -- the powerful cousins to vlookup. I am a little confused as to the scenario so another example might help but..

assuming you want to find F1 in a list A1 to A100. 
=MATCH(F1,A1:A100,0) will return where in the list A1:100 it found the text F1

then use index to return that value. =index(a1:a100,MATCH(F1,A1:A100,0))

If F1 was 'keyword' and it was the seventh word in a list A1:100
the match function returns 7
the index function returns keyword

Comment: I have multiple colums to match on

Comment: I have multiple colums to match on. Where file 1 col F = file 2 col K and file 1 col G = File 2 col AK and file 1 col H = file 2 col AF, etc where file 2 search area is A1:BN100

Comment: I'm sorry I am still having trouble visualizing what you are trying to do. 

In File 1, you have a column F which is searching in File 2 column K using what criteria? Are you trying to match one item in File 1 against the entire column K in File 2? 

A small picture or an example sheet would help out a lot here I think.

Comment: I'm sorry I would like to add an example but don't know how to here.  Let me explain again.  It's like a 2 file match.  File 1 is the driver.  So as I loop thru file 1 I need to use the values in the six cols mentioned for the current row and find the equivelant row in file 2 using the columns also mentioned earlier.  Only when I find a match do I move the data to file 1 (current row).  Again compare the values of the six named columns in file 1 to the values in the six named columns anywhere in file 2.